# How to create custom additional fields in UserProfile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create a custom user fields. I've added to the registration form. Everything works properly, automatically creates the table but the field *City* is `NULL`. Anyone know why this happens?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("MySql.Data.MySqlClient")
    {
    }
}
```

**MySqlInitializer.cs**

```
public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            context.Database.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
            string.Format(
              "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
              "[users]"));

            if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Register.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**AccountViewModels.cs** in *public class RegisterViewModel* added

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

[image: null]

Comment: And what does your controller look like where you create the user?

Comment: And have you updated the RegisterViewModal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the City variable when you create the user object:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, City = model.City  };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

**EDIT:** Updated code to use your code.